# Angular CRUD to and from API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, api

I am trying to build a system that you upload photos add photos to array, save photos. When you save photo it posts to a API, also the Array is per populated with the current images saved to the API on last visit.

So

1. User uploads photos and sees a preview (Working)
2. Click add and it adds the preview image to the array (NOT WORKING FULLY)
3. Save updated array and post to API. (Working but dose not update array async)

**In Summery**

I need a list of images that is pulled from a API and the images can be deleted and added then posted back to the API.

**What I have working**

You upload image, then click add then save and refresh and the images just posted to the API print out.

However when I add the image I can not see until I save and refresh.

I need the image to display with the list of images but not post until I click save, I also need a way to delete individual images.

See screen shot of program and list of images from API printed out

[image]

**HTML**

```
    <div ng-repeat="campaign in campaigns" class="campaign-container">

    <div class="dynamic-upload-container">
        <div class="preview"><img style="height: 100px; width: 100px" ng-src="{{preview}}" alt="preview image"></div>
        <div class="upload-new">
            <input id="fileinput" ng-model="file" type="file" ng-model-instant="" name="file" accept="image/*" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadImage(this)">

        </div>
        <div class="slots-container">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th><p>Campaign Name</p></th>
                    <th> <strong>{{campaign.c_name}}</strong></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><p>Max images allowed</p></td>
                    <td><strong>{{campaign.max_slots}}</strong></td>
                </tr>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <button ng-click="addImage()">Add image</button>

            <!--<h3>these are the images pulled from API</h3>-->
            <!--<strong>{{campaign.slots}}</strong>-->

            <h3>these are the images added from preview</h3>
                <div ng-repeat="slot in campaign.slots"  class="slot">
                    <img ng-click="addImage()" style="height: 100px; width: 100px" ng-src="{{slot.base_image}}" alt="slot image">

                    <!--<strong ng-click="addImage()" style="height: 100px; width: 100px">{{campaign.slots}}}</strong>-->

                    <button ng-click="removeImage(slot)">Remove Image</button>
            </div>

             <button ng-click="SaveImage()">Save to API</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
  .controller('Dashboard', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {

    $scope.campaigns =[];
    $scope.preview = '';
    $scope.slots = [];
    $scope.maxSlots = 5; // this dynamic

    $scope.safeApply = function(fn) {
        if (this.$root) {
            var phase = this.$root.$$phase;
            if (phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest') {
                if (fn && (typeof(fn) === 'function')) {
                    fn();
                }
            } else {
                this.$apply(fn);
            }
        } else {
            fn();
        }
    };

    $scope.debug = function(){
        console.log('this is debug');
        console.log($scope.slots.length);
    };

    $scope.uploadImage = function () {
        // console.log('we are here');
        input = document.getElementById('fileinput');
        file = input.files[0];
        size = file.size;
        if (size < 650000) {
            var fr = new FileReader;
            fr.onload = function (e) {
                var img = new Image;

                img.onload = function () {
                    var width = img.width;
                    var height = img.height;
                    if (width == 1920 && height == 1080) {
                        $scope.preview = e.target.result;
                        $scope.perfect = "you added a image";
                        $scope.$apply();

                    } else {
                        $scope.notPerfect = "incorrect definitions";
                        $scope.$apply();
                    }
                };
                img.src = fr.result;
            };

            fr.readAsDataURL(file);
        } else {
            $scope.notPerfect = "to big";
        }
    };

    $scope.addImage = function () {
        if ($scope.slots.length < $scope.maxSlots) {
            $scope.slots.push({
                "slot_id": $scope.slots.length + 1,
                "base_image": $scope.preview,
                "path_image": ""
            });
            $scope.safeApply

        } else {
            window.alert("you have to delete a slot to generate a new one");
            // console.log('you have to delete a slot to generate a new one')
        }
    };

    $scope.SaveImage = function () {
        $http({
            url: "http://www.site.co.uk/ccuploader/campaigns/updateSlots",
            method: "POST",
            data: { 'campaign': "ben", 'slots': $scope.slots },
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        }).then(function (response) {
            // success
            console.log('success');
            console.log("then : " + JSON.stringify(response));
            // location.href = '/cms/index.html';
        }, function (response) { // optional
            // failed
            console.log('failed');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        });
    };

    $scope.removeImage = function(s) {
        $scope.campaign.slots.splice($scope.campaign.slots.indexOf(s), 1);
    };

    $scope.GetData = function () {
        $http({
            url: "http://www.site.co.uk/ccuploader/campaigns/getCampaign",
            method: "POST",
            date: {},
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        }).then(function (response) {
            // success
            console.log('you have received the data ');
            console.log(response);

            $scope.campaigns = response.data;
            //$scope.slots = data.data[0].slots;

        }, function (response) {
            // failed
            console.log('failed getting campaigns goo back to log in page.');
            console.log(response);
        });
    };

    $scope.GetData();
})
```

Comment: what exactly is your issue? can't save the new image? Do you have an array of images and isn't that updating on adding or deleting an image?

Comment: So at the moment I can print out my images from the API, I can also add images to a list by clicking add image i can then remove that image and then save to add to the API when I refresh I see the base64 of the images i just saved. I want to for the array of base64 images from the API to populate the list and the ability to remove and add

Comment: Ill Update my question to make it easier to read

Comment: Yes and no, It solved a error. but some functions of my program are not working as expected, like click add image it adds the image so that on save it post to the API but i can not see the image in the list on the pic until i refresh and save. I also cant remove individual images.

Answer (score 0):

Been solved by changing the `GetData` function path to pull from

```
 $scope.GetData = function () {
        $http({
            url: "http://www.ccuktech.co.uk/ccuploader/campaigns/getCampaign",
            method: "POST",
            date: {},
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        }).then(function (response) {
            // success
            console.log('you have received the data ');
            // console.log(response);
            $scope.campaigns = response.data;
            $scope.slots = response.data[0].slots;

        }, function (response) {
            // failed
            console.log('failed getting campaigns goo back to log in page.');
            // console.log(response);
        });
    };
```